# Elasticsearch query using of Must and must not

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, esquery

In ES query i have IP field , now i want to exclude some IP's series.
ip series which should excluded :192.168.0.0/16

here is query trying nd I'm getting error.

```
 {
 "size": 0,
 "query": {
  "bool": {
  "filter": [
    {
          "match_all": {
            
          }
        },
    {
      "range": {
        "timestamp": {
          "gte": "now-1y",
          "lte": "now",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "must_not": {
   "match":{
     "ip_address":"192.168*"
   }
  }
 }
 }
 }
```

Error:
failed to create query: '192.168*' is not an IP string literal

any other way to exclude the this IP series?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range query to exclude all the documents that have IP addresses in the range of `192.168.*`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1y",
              "lte": "now",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "range": {
          "ip_addr": {
            "gte": "192.168.0.0",
            "lt": "192.168.255.255"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

You can use multiple range queries inside the `must_not` block, to exclude multiple range of IP address

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "range": {
            "ip_addr": {
              "gte": "192.168.0.0",
              "lt": "192.168.255.255"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "ip_addr": {
              "gte": "10.0.0.0",
              "lt": "10.255.255.255"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ESCoder , can we add multiple IP ranges in this? like to add 10.0.0.0

Comment: @mkail do you want to include `10.0.0.0` in the range query ?

Comment: yes want to include this range in query

Comment: can you help? want to add multiple ranges of IP's.

Comment: @mkail its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)